# Singular value decomposition of sum of single particle operators

Tags: operator-algebras, matrix-decomposition, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

here is my question.
Suppose to have an operator $L$ in a composite Hilbert space $A\otimes B$
which can be written as sum of single particle operator as:
\begin{equation}
L = (L_0\otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes L_0).
\end{equation} 
Suppose now that your numerical capabilities allow you to compute the singular value decomposition of $L_0=U_0S_0V_0^\dagger$.

Is it possible to write the SVD of the operator $L=USV^\dagger$ using just tensor product or compositions of the matrices $U_0$, $S_0$ and $V_0$?

My intuition says that is should be possible as it is possible to compute the spectrum and the inverse of $L$ just knowing the full spectrum of $L_0$. From a more physical point of view this seems to me reasonable since the *properties*  of composite systems with no interactions between the subsystems can be always deduced from the local properties (I mean, the spectrum of an ensamble of non-interacting spins or electrons can be deduced knowing the spectrum of a single particle).

Thank you very much in advance,
best regards

Alberto

Answer (score 1):

Let us put your intuition to the test. Let $A=B=\mathbb C^2$, and
$$
L_0=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt2&3/\sqrt2\\ \sqrt2&-3/\sqrt2 \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now
$$
L=L_0\otimes I+I\otimes L_0=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt2&3/\sqrt2&0&0\\ \sqrt2&-3/\sqrt2&0&0\\0&0&\sqrt2&3/\sqrt2\\0&0&\sqrt2&-3/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt2&0&3/\sqrt2&0\\0&\sqrt2&0&3/\sqrt2\\ \sqrt2&0&-3/\sqrt2&0\\0&\sqrt2&0&-3/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}2\sqrt2&3/\sqrt2&3/\sqrt2&0\\ \sqrt2&-1/\sqrt2&0&3/\sqrt2\\ \sqrt2&0&-1/\sqrt2&3/\sqrt2\\0&\sqrt2&\sqrt2&-3\sqrt2\end{bmatrix},
$$
and (according to Wolfram Alpha)
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}5.746&0&0&0\\ 0&4.36177&0&0\\ 0&0&1/\sqrt2&0\\0&0&0&0.677124\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}-0.181482 & 0.912785 & 0 & 0.365907 \\
0.392625 & 0.284406 & 0.707107 & -0.514741 \\
0.392625 & 0.284406 & -0.707107 & -0.514741 \\
-0.811637 & 0.0710617 & 0& -0.579823
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$ 
V=\begin{bmatrix}0.103934 & 0.776329 & 0 & -0.6217\\
-0.315078 & 0.420862 & -0.707107 & 0.472865\\
-0.315078 & 0.420862 & 0.707107 & 0.472865\\
0.889185 &0.207517 & 0 & 0.407783
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Or consider
$$
L_0=\begin{bmatrix}5/2&-1/2\\-1/2&5/2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2.&-1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2.&-1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}^*
$$
(same $U_0$ and $L_0$). 
Note that $S_0$ is also the same as the previous example. Now
$$
L=L_0\otimes I+I\otimes L_0=\begin{bmatrix}5/2&-1/2&0&0\\-1/2&5/2&0&0\\0&0&5/2&-1/2\\0&0&-1/2&5/2\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}5/2&0&-1/2&0\\0&5/2&0&-1/2\\-1/2&0&5/2&0\\0&-1/2&0&5/2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}5&-1/2&-1/2&0\\-1/2&5&0&-1/2\\-1/2&0&5&-1/2\\0&-1/2&-1/2&5\end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}4&0&0&0\\ 0&5&0&0\\ 0&0&5&0\\ 0&0&0&6\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Of course this doesn't show that there is no relation between $U,S,V$ and $U_0,S_0,V_0$; but if there is one, it's unlikely that it is simple.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I already noticed that simple ways like the one you presented are not effective unfortunately :)

What we are missing in my opinion is how to exploit the fact that the operators $L_0\otimes\mathbb{I}$ and $\mathbb{I}\otimes L_0$ do commute. This is the basic fact that allows one to easily compute the inverse of $L$ for example. Just to let you know I'm interested in computing the SVD of such operator because in this way I can compute its Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse.